# Using JustGage with Angular Materal

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, justgage

I want to use [JustGage](http://justgage.com/) with Angular Material with `ng-repeat` directive. With one gadge every thing is ok. But when I use it with `ng-repeat` it doesn't work. I have tried custom directive and plugins also. Is there any way to use JustGage with `ng-repeat` ? Or any other gadge that works right with angular material.

Comment: did you try this angular justgage directives : https://www.google.fr/search?q=justgage+angular&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=l76UVu-ILYe4aprXvIgP

Comment: yes I have tried @AlainIb

Comment: put some code or a 'working' example on plunkr with the part that didn't work. other people will help more easily with code